# how to get the value in while loop for python?

Tags: python, while-loop

I have the following simple while loop:

```
a=0
while a < 5:
    a+=1
    print(a)

Result:
1
2
3
4
5
```

I would like to get the final value of a (in this case, a = 5)

I did some research and fount that return / yield may help

but I got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Is there any way I can get this final value of a?

Comment: Your code won't produce that output.

Comment: @Selcuk is there any way i can do that? or i cant get the value inside while loop?

Comment: you need to define a function to leverage return/yield.

Comment: Do you need to access the value of `a` equal to `5` after while loop ends ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that your code in the question and your output do not match. Please post your actual code and/or your actual output, not hypothetical ones.

Comment: @PrashantKumar yes. I want to assign a = 5 after the while loop ends

Comment: In that case you have to do anything extra. Check my answer below with explanation.

Comment: @Kilometers Go ahead, just do it then. Just write `a = 5` after the loop. You can do it. On the other hand, `a` *is* `5` already after the loop, so why bother?

Comment: Funny @JanChristophTerasa. Good

Answer (score 0):

The above code will print the number 5 five times. You can print the value of 'a' outside of the while loop to get the last value.

```
a=0
while a < 5:
    a+=1
print(a)
```

the result will be 5

Comment: oh sorry i think i make a mistake. I have changed my question. I would actually like to set a=5 after the while loop end.

Comment: The value of a will be 5 once after the loop ends

Answer (score 0):

You are increasing the value of `a` inside loop. After the loop ends you can directly use that value anyway you want.

You don't have to return or yield anything for this.

Like this :

```
a=0
while a < 5:
    a+=1

print(a)

>>> 5
```

The line where I have printed `a`, I am able to get the value I set inside loop. So after loop ends you can just access `a` and it will you `5`.